# reversing string with reversed function, print shows memory location but not the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am reversing string with reversed function, of course I asigned to variable when I print it, shows memory location but not the string value

```
user_input = "12345678"
reversed_odd_digit_sum = 0
cc = reversed(user_input)
print (cc)
```

I recived output like this
`<reversed object at 0x0002DA978110>`

how can I extract actual reversed string than memory location

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed

Comment: Use the _[list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list)_ _function_, _list(reversed(user_input))_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) returns an iterator. So to get reversed string, consume the iterator with `str.join` for example:

```py
user_input = "12345678"

cc = reversed(user_input)
print("".join(cc))
```

Prints:

```
87654321
```

Comment: ...or *print (*cc, sep='')*